# Macro that calls itself differently depending on the number of arguments

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I am trying to create a simple `map` macro that should be called like this:

```rust
let c = "asdads";
map![
    a: "b",
    c, // auto expand, same as `c: "asdads"`
    d: 345
]
```

and return a `crate::Map(&[(String, String)])`.

I have wrapped it in a struct to implement some properties like `Display` or `Debug`, and I am using a reference to a slice because a slice is not `Sized`.

I can write a macro that parses only the full form (`a: "b"`) or the short form (just `a`) but I can't think of one that will be able to match both.

The one matching the short form:

```rust
($($key:ident),*) => {
    crate::Map(&[
        $((stringify!($key).to_string(), $key.to_string())),*
    ][..])
};
```

The one matching the full form:

```rust
($($key:ident : $value:expr),*) => {
    crate::Map(&[
        $((stringify!($key).to_string(), $value.to_string())),*
    ][..])
};
```

What I have tried: making two separate macros that match only one line and then passing a `tt` to it.

```rust
macro_rules! map_one {
    ($key:ident) => {
        (stringify!($key).to_string(), $key.to_string())
    };
    ($key:ident : $value:expr) => {
        (stringify!($key).to_string(), $value.to_string())
    };
}

macro_rules! map {
    ($($tt:tt),*) => {
        crate::Map(&[
            $(map_one!($tt)),*
        ][..])
    };
}
```

I get a compile error:

```
no rules expected the token `:`
while trying to match `,`.
```

Comment: hint: `key: "value"` is not a single token tree. It is three.

Comment: @PitaJ thank you! i thought token trees capture everything:) ill post the answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tt` matcher matches a token tree, which is either a single token (ident, operator, `:`, etc) or a set of tokens grouped within a pair of parenthesis, square brackets, or curly braces.

So `key: "value"` is actually three `tt`s. The way to work around this is to match optionally on the `: $value:expr` part with a `$()?` group, them pass the whole thing along to your `map_one` macro:

```rust
macro_rules! map {
    ($($key:ident $(: $value:expr)?),*) => {
        crate::Map(&[
            $(map_one!($key $(: $value)?)),*
        ][..])
    };
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b8e3678bde34df9347b22146a0e12612)

I would also recommend merging the two macros using the `@prefix` pattern:

```rust
macro_rules! map {
    (@one $key:ident) => {
        (stringify!($key).to_string(), $key.to_string())
    };
    (@one $key:ident : $value:expr) => {
        (stringify!($key).to_string(), $value.to_string())
    };
    ($($key:ident $(: $value:expr)?),*) => {
        crate::Map(&[
            $(map!(@one $key $(: $value)?)),*
        ][..])
    };
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a6be23986fcf7e37995af94baf862bc6)